# why am I seeing a value error? adv_fml. lopez de prado

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading

This code is a snippet from Lopez De Prado *Advances in Financial Machine Learning* page 44

```
def getDailyVol(close,span0=100):
    # daily vol reindexed to close

    df0=close.index.searchsorted(close.index-pd.Timedelta(days=1))
    df0=df0[df0>0]   
    df0=(pd.Series(close.index[df0-1], 
                   index=close.index[close.shape[0]-df0.shape[0]:]))   

    try:
        df0=close.loc[df0.index]/close.loc[df0.values].values-1 # daily rets
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error: {e}\nplease confirm no duplicate indices')
    df0=df0.ewm(span=span0).std().rename('dailyVol')
    return df0
```

The parameters of the function are close and span. In the function statement the close is not a dataFrame of which I called `data['Close']`. Tried to create a variable for that index.Error: name 'close' is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to QSE. Perhaps this question is more suited for SO as it's purely syntax related? I have tried the script from MLDP's book and it works just fine. Using yahoo finance data:

```python
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime

def getDailyVol(close,span0=100):
    # daily vol reindexed to close

    df0=close.index.searchsorted(close.index-pd.Timedelta(days=1))
    df0=df0[df0>0]
    df0=(pd.Series(close.index[df0-1],
                   index=close.index[close.shape[0]-df0.shape[0]:]))

    try:
        df0=close.loc[df0.index]/close.loc[df0.values].values-1 # daily rets
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error: {e}\nplease confirm no duplicate indices')
    df0=df0.ewm(span=span0).std().rename('dailyVol')
    return df0

ticker = "SPY"
instrument = yf.Ticker(ticker)
data = instrument.history(start=datetime(2012,1,1), end=datetime.now())
result = getDailyVol(data['Close'], span0=63)
print(result)
```

Perhaps topic for another time, but having read some of MLDP's work, I must say that I am not a fan of his coding style (e.g. rarely comments, disregards any kind of Python coding convention etc.).